# Could not load DLL or dependency for ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll

I am very new to the .NET framework, and have been stuck on this issue for a week now.

I've been given a C# codebase, that is composed of several sub-projects which make use of DLLs compiled in C++. Each of these projects are inter-related, as they reference each other (non-circular).

If I create a basic Windows Forms Application, I can call functions from these DLLs no problem, by adding a reference to one of these sub-projects. However, if I create a very basic ASP.NET web app (which builds and runs fine on its own), it will break as soon as I add a reference to the sub-project I need.

By breaking, I mean I am given this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'XXXXX.DLL' or one of its
>   dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

I have done a lot of reading on this, since it seems to be a fairly common error, but none of the attempted solutions have worked.

To generalize, my main question is: Given two projects (one a windows form C# application, and the other an ASP.NET web application), both located in the same directory referencing the same project/DLLS, why does the web application struggle in locating the proper DLLs and/or dependencies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running the app in IIS or IISExpress?

Comment: Running on IIS Express

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET application, have you tried compiling the DLL's and copying them directly into your /bin directory?  That way you're eliminating the dependency and any reference issues VS may be choking on.

Then be sure to remove the references from your project so it's only using what it finds directly in the /bin directory.  See if that works for you.

Once you're sure the issue is truly the references vs the DLL's themselves, and you project builds completely, try adding the references back in....be sure to do a clean of the project, then a rebuild.

If that still doesn't work, make sure both projects are not in the same solution.  I had this issue not too long ago and it only seemed to work when I removed the other projects from the solution, opened another instance of VS2015 and then I was able to get everything working.

I know, I know....not really an answer if that ends up working, but when it comes to Microsoft's products sometimes we need to get a little creative.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I have made sure that all of DLL's are copied into the /bin directory. If I remove the reference from the project though, how can I still instantiate objects or call functions from the DLLs inside the /bin directory?

I tried referencing the DLLs directory and not including the projects in the same solution, although the same error still persisted. Still really confused why all this problem only occurs with the web application, but not with a desktop windows form application.